# How to update descriptions for my published add-in?

Tags: office-addins, office-store

Our team already have an add-in published on AppSource, and currently we'd like to update the description for this add-in.

Could anyone help on how to do this?

I tried to update on Partner Center, but I didn't find proper way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just need to know how to update the description.